# Exceptions are not caught in a secondary thread, causing segfault

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, thread-safety, mips

I cross-compile for a MIPS-based platform. 
The following code causes segfault, backtrace leads to __cxa_throw:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <exception>
#include <thread>

#include <execinfo.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void handler(int sig) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
  void *array[10];
  size_t size;

  // get void*'s for all entries on the stack
  size = backtrace(array, 10);

  fprintf(stderr, "Error: signal %d:\n", sig);
  // print out all the frames to stderr
  backtrace_symbols_fd(array, size, STDERR_FILENO);
  exit(1);
}

void deco()
{
    puts("Secondary thread started");
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        try {
            puts("throwing");
            throw std::runtime_error("test exception");
        }
        catch (std::exception & e)
        {
            puts("catched");
            puts(e.what());
        }
        puts("going on");
    }
    puts("Secondary thread ending");
}


int main()
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, handler);
    std::thread t2(deco);
    t2.join();
    return 0;
}
```

my makefile:

```
all: build

build: 
    /opt/mips/bin/mips-linux-gnu-g++  \
          -std=c++11 -O3 -mips32r2 -mtune=xburst -mmxu2 -mhard-float -mel -static -pthread -g -rdynamic \
          -Wl,--no-export-dynamic -Wl,--exclude-libs,ALL -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,--as-needed \
          cv_test.cpp -o j_test \
          -lm -latomic -lrt
    cp ./j_test /srv/tftp/j_test

clean:
    rm -rf *.o j_test
```

The compiler is some ingenic custom build: mips-linux-gnu-g++ (Ingenic r3.2.1-gcc520 2017.12-15) 5.2.0

No crash happens if deco() is run in the main thread instead of a secondary thread. Any clues? Probably a well-known gcc standard library issue? Are there a workaround?

Comment: The `handler` is doing way too much and violating what signal handlers are allowed to do.

Comment: What does running this code print? How far does the program get before crashing? (PS: It's "caught", not "catched").

Comment: My guess would be that `__cxa_throw` needs per-thread memory for the exception, but the runtime library fails to provide it for the additional threads. This is a subtle interface between compiler and standard library. The custom build you're dealing with might not have a matching standard library. This is aggravated by the fact that from a C++ perspective, a C library is part of C++, and from Linux perspective a C library is part of the OS, _and_ GCC treats those two C libraries as the same library.

Comment: Program prints "throwing" and then "Error: signal 11".

About TLS, thread_local variables seem to work

About library, I'm using a static build, so the compiler should use the library coming with the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with static linking.

Adding the line to LDFLAGS:

```
-Wl,--whole-archive -lpthread -lc -Wl,--no-whole-archive
```

solves the problem for me, even though executable size becomes larger.